# Find angle (slope) of collision plane?

Tags: c++, 3d, mathematics, glm

I have implemented a collision and response system based on the famous "[Improved Collision detection and Response](http://www.peroxide.dk/papers/collision/collision.pdf)" paper. However I'm having an issue with objects sliding backwards on slopes. I believe I could circumvent this issue if I understood how to find the angle of the plane of which my object is colliding with. Take the below screenshot as an example of the situation:

[image]

I know the following data:

- Position of player object (the ellipsoid at the bottom of the ramp)
- Vertices of the collision triangle
- Normal of the collision triangle
- Intersection point between player object and collision triangle
- Penetration distance between player object and collision triangle

How can I use this information to determine the angle of the collision triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the normal of the collision triangle, then you can do a dot product with a normal pointing up (0, 1, 0), the result will be related to the angle of the surface (0 when is completety vertical, 1 when it's completely flat, and in between)

That should be really all, you check that against a threshold to determine if you want the ellipsoid to slide or not.

I actually followed that same paper and this is how I implemented (my Up vector was 0,0,1)

```
// Check if the slide is too steep for gravity 
if (is_gravity) {
    var v1 = vector_normalize(velocity),
        v2 = [0, 0, 1 * sign(v1[2])],
        dp = dot(v1, v2);

    if (dp <= 0.70) {
        return true;
    } 
}
```